Python reflex project compilation failed when child component is used to render in a based parent class
Having a base fragment to show some common stuff on each page and a child component -> which is a variable to change containing part:
def base_page(child: rx.Component, *args, **kwargs) -> rx.Component:
    if not isinstance(child, rx.Component):
        child = rx.heading("This is not a valid child element here!")

    return rx.fragment(
        # navbar(),
        rx.box(
            child,
            # bg=rx.color("accent", 3),
            padding="1em",
            width="100%",
            id='my-content-area-element',
        ),
        rx.logo(),
        rx.color_mode.button(position="bottom-left"),
    )

this is how child component is passed to base one:
def index() -> rx.Component:
    return base_page(rx.text("HEY"))

when you try to reflex run after -> this is where compilation stuck at 20%:
enter image description here
but if we change "child" variable directly inside base_page - and put it like this - it compiles perfectly fine and works:
    if not isinstance(child, rx.Component):
        child = rx.heading("This is not a valid child element here!")

    return rx.fragment(
        # navbar(),
        rx.box(
            # child,
            rx.text("HEY"),
            # bg=rx.color("accent", 3),
            padding="1em",
            width="100%",
            id='my-content-area-element',
        ),
        rx.logo(),
        rx.color_mode.button(position="bottom-left"),
    )

enter image description here
**Any idea how to fix this? **
Tried with different python versions and lib versions
Python versions:
3.9.2, 3.9.20, 3.11.10, 3.12.2, 3.12.6
Lib versions:
0.5.3, 0.5.10
Tried with different python versions and lib versions
Python versions:
3.9.2, 3.9.20, 3.11.10, 3.12.2, 3.12.6
Lib versions:
0.5.3, 0.5.10
OS versions:
MacOS Sonoma (M1Pro based Silicon CPU), MacOS Sequoia-DEV (Intel Core i7 based CPU)
Expectations: compilation went smoothly without errors
